Simplification of nonessential "I"
I am banging my head trying to simplify following expression to get rid of the nonessential "I" (I know, I can do it by hand, but this is only a toy example):
I (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2 x^2])

To get:
-Sqrt[1 - a^2] + Sqrt[1 - a^2 x^2]

Not even the following works:
Simplify[I  (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2 x^2]) , Assumptions -> {1 < a, 1 < x}]

Correction :
Simplify[I  (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2 x^2]) , Assumptions -> {1 > a, 1 > x}]


Updated the question.

The I is not nonessential. The two expression are not equivalent.

@azerbajdzan Simplify[I  (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2  x^2]) == Sqrt[1 - a^2] - Sqrt[1 - a^2  x^2], Assumptions -> {1 < a, 1 < x}] returns True

This works: Simplify[I   (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2  x^2]), Assumptions -> {-1 + a^2 < 0, -1 + a^2  x^2 < 0}]. So does Simplify[I   (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2  x^2]), Assumptions -> {-1 < a < 1, -1 < x < 1}].

@ChrisK It is not the goal of OP to simplify that expression. He's goal is to simplify the expression without Assumptions -> {1 < a, 1 < x}, and this is not equivalent in this case. It is evident from PO's sentence "Not even the following works:".

@ChrisK Notice also that OP changed his second expression just an hour ago (swapping + and -) without any explanation. This affects under which circumstances the identity holds, but in general for all x and a it never holds.

Use ComplexExpand.
Assuming[0 < a < 1 && 0 < x < 1, 
 I  (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2  x^2]) // ComplexExpand // 
  Simplify]

(*-Sqrt[1 - a^2] + Sqrt[1 - a^2 x^2]*)


How about a brute force method for now until better method is found :)
e = I  (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2  x^2])
Expand[e] /. Complex[0, b_]*Sqrt[any_] :> Sqrt[any*Complex[0, b]^2]



Another possibility
expr = I (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2 x^2]);
(Simplify[# /. {Complex[0, 1] -> Sqrt[-c], 
                Complex[0, -1] -> -Sqrt[-c]}, 
          Assumptions -> {1 < a, 1 < x, c == 1}]) & /@ Expand[expr]


By playing around I found that although
Simplify[I   (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2  x^2]), Assumptions -> {a < 1, x < 1}]

does not work, it works if we constrict (although superfluous) the variables more:
Simplify[I   (Sqrt[-1 + a^2] - Sqrt[-1 + a^2  x^2]), Assumptions -> {0 < a < 1, 0 < x < 1}]

-Sqrt[1 - a^2] + Sqrt[1 - a^2 x^2]

